# How to get specific time using UTC offset in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

I'm working on writing a test case which is time-zone dependent. For this problem, I need to have a method which takes a UTC offset string as a parameter (e.g. "UTC-09:00", "UTC+03:00", etc), and returns what 10:00 (24-hour clock format) in that offset is equivalent to in my own time zone (Europe/Stockholm). Similar to how you can Google "10:00 AM Finnish time in Swedish time", and it'll return 09:00 AM.

I've looked up many time zone-related queries here on StackOverflow, but none of them seem to apply very well to my problem. The only solution I can think of would be to use "if else" statements, like this:

```
if(utcOffset == "UTC+02:00"){
    // use Java.time to convert 10:00 from UTC+02:00 time zone to UTC+01:00
} else if(utcOffset == "UTC+03:00"){
    // use Java.time to convert 10:00 from UTC+03:00 time zone to UTC+01:00
} // etc
```

This solution seems far from ideal, and I'm not even sure how to use Java.time to convert specific times (the only examples I've seen use current time), so I was wondering if there's a clever solution out there that I'm missing.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if any vital information is missing from my question, I'd be happy to clarify.

Comment: See if this can help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

Comment: @pringi Thanks, I found that page previously when researching, but I can't quite understand how to use it to solve my problem. I should add that I'm quite new to programming as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OffsetDateTime to build your "10:00"(examples in here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.time/OffsetDateTime/index.htm)

For the timezone part use the ZonedDateTime (ex: UTC+1:00).

You can do something like this `offsetDateTime.adjustInto(zonedDateTime)`.

Comment: Also see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html and this http://codingjunkie.net/java-8-dates-part2/

Comment: Thank you! Took some tinkering but I seem to have a working solution now. :)